# OrmLite queryForAll doesn't work

Tags: java, android, generics, ormlite

I am trying to create a library which manages data. Part of it is storing stuff in databases. Since I don't know what the user of library wants to store, I am using generics. Here is my method to read a database table.

```
public <TEntity extends SyncableBase> List<TEntity> loadItems(Class clazz) {
    List<TEntity> listToReturn = new ArrayList<TEntity>();

    DatabaseHelperBase dbHelper = getDbHelper();
    Dao<TEntity, Integer> dao;
    try {
        dao = dbHelper.getDao(clazz); //Is this approach correct?
        listToReturn = dao.queryForAll(); //This doesn't work
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listToReturn;

}
```

And somewhere in my app (which consumes this library) I call this method like so:

```
List<ToDoCategory> catList = mirrorservice.<ToDoCategory>loadItems(ToDoCategory.class);
```

No matter what I do, the empty ArrayList is returned to `catList`. I tried similar approach with `queryForId` too. That didn't work either. Meanwhile, my `add` is working just fine!

I suspect that there is something wrong with the way I'm creating `Dao`. What is the problem?

Comment: I'm not the best dealing with generics, but since you don't get any answer I have to ask: Shouldn't it be `public <TEntity extends SyncableBase> List<TEntity> loadItems(Class<TEntity> clazz)` and List<ToDoCategory> catList = mirrorservice.<ToDoCategory>loadItems(ToDoCategory.class);`? Apart from that, your approach of obtaining the `dao` is correct.

Comment: @super-qua Thank you for pointing out the typo. I have edited the original question. Also, accepting `Class<TEntity>` instead of `Class` seems like a nice idea. Although compiler gives a warning, Simply using `Class` is sufficient. This may help me get rid of the warning.